# split data without using for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have  numpy array:

```
data = np.array(
    [  4, -5.5, -9.1, -12.2, -20.0, -20.5,
        82, 21, -3, -4, -5, -3,
        62, 51, 42, 33, 25, 12,
        -46, 29, 68, 86, 97, 122 ] )
```

I'm trying to split it into equal segments.
so the output should be:

```
output =  [  4, -5.5, -9.1, -12.2], 
          [-20.0, -20.5,82, 21],
          [ -3, -4, -5, -3],
          [62, 51, 42, 33],
          [ 25, 12, -46, 29],
          [ 68, 86, 97, 122 ]
```

I know that I can use list comprehension but is there another to do it using numpy?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want multiple arrays, or a single array containing segments of the original array?

Comment: Your output is not a valid python expression. Did you mean a nested list?

Comment: @ j1-lee sorry, yes I meant a nested list

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reshape()` to first convert the 1d-array into a 2d-array, and then use `tolist()` to convert it to a nested list.

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
    [  4, -5.5, -9.1, -12.2, -20.0, -20.5,
        82, 21, -3, -4, -5, -3,
        62, 51, 42, 33, 25, 12,
        -46, 29, 68, 86, 97, 122 ] )

output = data.reshape(-1, 4) # make it to have 4 columns, and let the number of rows be determined accordingly
print(output) # a 2d-array
output = output.tolist() # convert the 2d-array into a nested list
print(output) # a nested list [[4.0, -5.5, -9.1, -12.2], [-20.0, -20.5, 82.0, 21.0], [-3.0, -4.0, -5.0, -3.0], [62.0, 51.0, 42.0, 33.0], [25.0, 12.0, -46.0, 29.0], [68.0, 86.0, 97.0, 122.0]]
```

Comment: I was about to hit "submit". Beat me by a hair.